# list of fastai models

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, fast-ai

FastAI uses AWD-LSTM for text processing. They provide pretrained models with [`get_language_model()`](https://docs.fast.ai/text.models.html#get_language_model). But I can't find proper documentation on what's available.

Their [github example page](https://github.com/fastai/fastai/blob/master/examples/text.ipynb) is really a moving target. Model names such as `lstm_wt103` and `WT103_1` are used. In the forums I found `wt103RNN`.

Where can I find an updated list of pretrained models and their download URLs ?

Comment: Any chance you got an answer to your problem? I'm also looking to use pre-trained models but it's not explained where to load them and what steps to use

Comment: I should have accepted the answer below long ago. The URLs that can be imported should contain all valid models. Unfortunately, fastai changes their codebase extremely fast and does introduce breaking changes. Forum mentions of models such as lstm_wt103 etc are probably just outdated. So, long story short, use those URLs from fastai.datasets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URLs is defined in [fastai.datasets](https://github.com/fastai/fastai/blob/release-1.0.36/fastai/datasets.py#L7), there are constants for two models: WT103, WT103_1.

[AWS bucket](https://s3.amazonaws.com/fast-ai-modelzoo) has just the two models.